# How does Akka reach such a high performance?

Tags: multithreading, performance, akka, actor

Akka provides some numbers of its high performance:

> 50 million msg/sec on a single machine. Small memory footprint; ~2.5 million actors per GB of heap.

The actor behaves "like" a single thread, means that you can handle the messages in parallel. I'm just curious how is it implemented under the hood to be able to have ~2.5 million actors per GB of heap? Does that mean that I can execute 2.5 million parallel tasks using actors? Obviously you can not have so many threads per GB.

Comment: You should read the documentation about dispatchers: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: @Ryan this doc is good, thanks, but it doesn't give the the answer about so hight performance that is listed in the main page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 2.5 million of active actors to process 50 million msg/sec. Akka team achieved 50M msg/sec with 96 actors working on a 48-core machine (see a link with details below).

Basically, these numbers ("50 million msg/sec" and "~2.5 million actors per GB") are not related to each other.

"~2.5 million actors per GB" means that Akka actors are light-weight and have very little memory footprint (but of course they all can't be active at a time - this highly depends on the number of cores and number of threads in the dispatcher settings).

"50 million msg/sec" means that this level of performance can be achieved with careful tuning of the actor pool size and dispatcher settings ([see details here](http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single-machine)).